# Jquery: can we detect which link was clicked from ajaxStart

Tags: jquery

suppose i have links in table in header for sorting and link in footer for pagination.when click then ajax call start and from ajaxStart & ajaxComplete i show a busy loader. now i like to know can we get the element type or id which causes ajax start function.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    alert('pop');
    $('#loader').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('#loader').hide();
})
```

is it possible? thanks

Comment: No way check this link https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: How are you triggering the AJAX Start?

Comment: i am using webgrid in asp.net mvc which inject some code dynamically in page which start ajax call. i have no control on that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> suppose i have links in table in header for sorting and link in footer for pagination.when click then ajax call start and from
>   ajaxStart & ajaxComplete i show a busy loader. now i like to know can
>   we get the element type or id which causes ajax start function.

Use `click` event

```
$(links).click(function() {
  // set clicked element `data-clicked` to `true`
  $(this).data("clicked", true);
  // set `links` not clicked `data-clicked` to `false`
  $(links).not(this).data("clicked", false);
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
  // filter `links` , return element where 
  // `data-clicked` is `true`
  var elem = $(links).filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("clicked") === true
  });
  console.log(elem);
  alert('pop');
  $('#loader').show();
});
```

Comment: i need to know clicked link id from ajaxStart function.

Comment: @Mou Does `js` at jsfiddle return expected results ?